# DropDownList populates duplicate data after being used

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use 3 drop downs to filter data on the page. This is the second drop down below. It populates depending on what is selected in the first `Dropdownlist`.

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="subCatDDL"
                                     AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                     ItemType="E_Store_Template.Models.SubCategory"
                                    DataTextField="SubCategoryName"
                                     DataValueField="SubCategoryID"

                                     AutoPostBack="true"
                                     CssClass="FilterMenu" Visible="false">
                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="SubCategories"  Value="0" />

                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is the query that i use to grab all of the data for the second DropDownList.

```
List<SubCategory> query = _db.SubCategories
                       .Where(x => x.Category.CategoryID == DDLcatId)
                       .Distinct()
                       .ToList();



                    subCatDDL.DataSource = query;
                    subCatDDL.DataBind();
```

So i have tired alot of different things to clear the DropDownlist `subCatDDL.Items.Clear()` i tried setting the datasource = null before i repopulate it. I called .Distinct. Nothing has worked.

So basically if i select a item it will do a postback populate the items that i am filtering and then it creates a duplicate of that selected item in my Dropdownlist. If i mess around long enough i can make that second list full of duplicates. How can i fix this?

What is the best way to Clear a Dropdownlist and repopulate it when it is being populated from a `AutoPostBack="true"`?

Comment: Try remove "AppendDataBoundItems=True"

Comment: i would check inside of your page load. i bet you are populating it on postbacks as well as inside another function. the ddl.items.clear should have worked.

Comment: @mmeasor I am populating it on postbacks should i post all the code?

Comment: The more code you post, the more we can help

Comment: I note that the AutoPostBack is set to "true". so do you do the query with checking the ispostback?

Comment: i would post the page load, and any code where you are touching that dropdown

Comment: @mmeasor Put your first comment as a answer that is what it was!!

Answer (score 0):

remove AppendDataBoundItems="true" &                              ItemType="E_Store_Template.Models.SubCategory" and make sure that you are not using subCatDDL.Items.Add() after setting datasource